# Equivalent of retaining instance variable under ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, restkit

I'm using `RestKit` to develop a RESTful application. I have a wrapper object that actually handles requests and even acts as the `delegate` for the `RKObjectManager`. I am experiencing an issue related to how ARC handles instance variables and retaining them, and it is clear to me that I do not understand how ARC works.

So when I do this, it fails (with error related to message sent to deallocated instance)

`MyTestClient *testClient = [[MyTestClient alloc] init];`

but when I declare a property and do this, all is fine:

`self.testClient = [[MyTestClient alloc] init];`

From what I understand, under ARC, an instance variable is always `strong` by default, but it's lifecycle is the scope of the method in which it's declared.

Since I can't do `[testClient retain]`, is my only option to make it a property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variables are strong by default and will be retained within their scope. So in the first example, the object will only be retained until the end of the function. In the second, since you have an instance variable, it will be retained until the owning object is deallocated (presumably long enough for you in this case). Your best option is to make it a property, but you could also just make it an instance variable. It will do the same thing for you in this case.

A simple way to think about it is you need to have a strong pointer to an object until you no longer need it around.

Comment: Ok - so basically, since ARC has to make certain assumptions about the scope of your variables, you need to make them available everywhere  you are going to need them somehow (whether through a property, member variable, etc)?

Comment: Exactly. There are a couple of good resources on ARC. I'd recommend reading up on it. Most of the time you don't have to worry about memory stuff with ARC, but it helps to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to retain in ARC would be to have a pointer pointing to it. As long as you have something pointing to the object, that object will be kept alive. Hence you can use properties, instance variables, even instances pointing to those objects.

Like wbyoung said. You are getting the error because testClient is only alive inside where you initiated it, this being viewdidload, or init, or w/e.